# Dask AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_repr_data'

Tags: python, pandas, dask, attributeerror

I have a Dask Dataframe, seems to be well loaded, however I am not able to save it, due to a '?' somewhere in the DF.

What I did:

```
def replace(x: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return x.replace('?',np.nan)
ddf_short0 = ddf_short.map_partitions(replace)
ddf_short0
```

What it returned:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py
>   in **call**(self, obj)
>       670                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
>       671                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
>   --> 672             printer.pretty(obj)
>       673             printer.flush()
>       674             return stream.getvalue()
>
> /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py
>   in pretty(self, obj)
>       381                             if callable(meth):
>       382                                 return meth(obj, self, cycle)
>   --> 383             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
>       384         finally:
>       385             self.end_group()
>
> /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py
>   in _default_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
>       501     if _safe_getattr(klass, '**repr**', None) not in _baseclass_reprs:
>       502         # A user-provided repr. Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
>   --> 503         _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
>       504         return
>       505     p.begin_group(1, '<')
>
> /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py
>   in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
>       699     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
>       700     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
>   --> 701     output = repr(obj)
>       702     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
>       703         if idx:
>
> /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py
>   in **repr**(self)
>       392 
>       393     def **repr**(self):
>   --> 394         data = self._repr_data.to_string(max_rows=5, show_dimensions=False)
>       395         return """Dask {klass} Structure:
>       396 {data}
>
> /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py
>   in **getattr**(self, key)    2518             return
>   new_dd_object(merge(self.dask, dsk), name,    2519
>   meta, self.divisions)
>   -> 2520         raise AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute %r" % key)    2521     2522     def **dir**(self):
>
> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_repr_data'

Any ideas? Thanks